# Importing landuse (raster) to polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, polygon, arcgis-pro, import, land-use

I have a raster file (Landuse classes) and a polygon file (administrative units).

How can I import the raster landuse classes to the administrative limits so I can find what landuse classes are in every unit, so I can perform spatial analysis, like area of a certain landuse in a certain unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can polygonize the raster, clip it by boundary, and then get the land area of each land use per boundary. Tabulate Area in ArcGIS is the closest tool I can think of.

Comment: Tabulate area will work between polygons and original raster